# Reducing lock contention for a caching utility, or make it totally lockless but threadsafe

Tags: java, concurrency, cache, singleton, redis

My Java program is a module called `configProxy` which fetches configuration entries from a remote node (say from a Redis instance). When the caller calls the `get(configKey)` method, this module checks in a local cache (a concurrent hashmap) to see if the setting is already cached.  If not, it fetches the setting from a Redis instance, caches it and then returns.

The implementation of this singleton class:

```
public class ConfigProxy {

/** This is our one-n-only instance **/
private static ConfigProxy _instance = null;

/** default values for some keys which may not be declared **/
private HashMap<String, String> _defaults = null;

private Jedis jedisConfigConnection;

// hash map for storing the data of config proxy as a cache for each
// String,List and Hash
// to prevent constant hitting to Redis
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> _cacheStrings = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> _cacheLists = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> _cacheHashes = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>();


/*
 * Takes host and port as parameters to connect with redis instance
 */
private ConfigProxy(String host, int port) throws ConnectionException {

    try {

        jedisConfigConnection = new Jedis(host, port);
        jedisConfigConnection.ping();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConnectionException("Unable to connect to Config Server");
    }

}

public static ConfigProxy getInstance(String host, int port)
        throws ConnectionException {

    if (_instance == null) _instance = new ConfigProxy(host, port);
    return _instance;
}

/**
 * Overloaded version which doesn't take any parameters. Inorder for this
 * call to succeed, the caller, somewhere should have called
 * getInstance(host, port), once. else this throws InitializationException.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws NotInitializedException
 */
public static ConfigProxy getInstance() throws NotInitializedException {
    if (_instance == null) throw new NotInitializedException();
    return _instance;
}

...

/**
 * Returns a configuration setting value either from cache or from a
 * configured Redis instance.
 * 
 *  If the given setting was not cached, and it needs to be fetched
 *  from Redis, then the code locks this object 
 * @param key
 * @return The value configured for the specified key, if one exists.
 */
public String get(String key) {
    if (_cacheStrings.containsKey(key))
        return _cacheStrings.get(key);
    else {
        synchronized (jedisConfigConnection) {
            String res = (String) jedisConfigConnection.get(key);
            if (res == null) return res;
            _cacheStrings.put(key, res);
            return res;
        }
    }
}

...
...
}
```

Currently, if the key already exists in the cache, the `get(configkey)` doesn't lock, and simply returns the value from cache.  However the get function (shown at the bottom in the above code), obtains a lock on jedis connection object, before attempting to fetch data from Redis.

I want to know:

- If this is correct, or if I obtain a lock on the entire "this" (`configProxy`) object.
- If it is possible to improve it in any way to further reduce locking contentions, as this will be used in a multi-threaded high txn oriented environment.

***EDIT***

After review, this is my next version of the get method.

```
public String get(String key) {

    if (_cacheStrings.containsKey(key)) return _cacheStrings.get(key);
    else {
        String res = null;
        synchronized (jedisConfigConnection) { res = (String) jedisConfigConnection.get(key); }
        if (res != null) _cacheStrings.putIfAbsent(key, res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Definitely do not lock on the `ConfigProxy` instance. Somebody else could acquire a lock on it and then you'd be up the creek. Only lock on private instances that you have the only copy of.
2. Strictly speaking, you could use `putIfAbsent` and get rid of the lock altogether, but then you're potentially seeing multiple Redis calls for the same key. You should check both outside and inside the `synchronized` block to see if the key is there yet. If two threads both hit that barrier in the else, the first one will put a value in the map .. then the second one will go do it again. The first check keeps you out of the `synchronized` block, and the second one lets you exit it early.
3. I'm not entirely convinced that a `Concurrent` map buys you anything here, since you're managing the `put`s using synchronization. I might be wrong - there may be black magic around `get`s that I'm unaware of.
4. Random convention stuff - Java doesn't use underscores to indicate instance variables. Always use curly braces. Make everything final that you can.

Comment: Hi Eric,
Trying to reduce sync code, by only putting jedis call in sync block as below:

public String get(String key) {

  if (_cacheStrings.containsKey(key)) return _cacheStrings.get(key);
  else {
   String res = null;
   synchronized (jedisConfigConnection) { res = (String) jedisConfigConnection.get(key); }
   if (res != null) _cacheStrings.put(key, res);
   return res;
  }
Hope this helps..?

Comment: I shd have realized that "add comment" doesn't format the text so we can't paste code here :(

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath You should look at the accepted answer to this question for the correct way to use putIfAbsent: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752194/best-practice-to-use-concurrentmaps-putifabsent`